# Textbox default value - OutSystems

Tags: outsystems

I have developed an application with OutSystems where I have an entity attribute whose data-type is integer. Now  when I open up that particular form for editing purpose the entity attribute being of integer type the value by default in that textbox is displayed as 0(zero). I have to manually delele the default value and then enter some other value.

Is there any chance by which I see a 'cleared'(blank) textbox when I open up the form for editing.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to go to the input properties and in the *Null Value* set it to 0.

Comment: Miguel Antunes - Thanks for your quick concern, it worked fine.
Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 2):

Also as datatype is **integer**, in the null value property box I typed `TextToInteger("")` and it also works fine. This is another alternative to the above provided answer.